# Troubleshooting Motion package on raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian-stretch

I recently made my raspberry pi into a livestream camera in the kitchen which we use to check up on the dog.

It’a been working all day, but in the last hour or so nothing is being streamed, yet the daemon remains on and I’ve reset the service several times, as well as rebooting the pi.

Does anybody know of anything that could cause such a thing to happen?

EDIT: After turning off output_pictures in /etc/motion/motion.conf, now what seems to be happening is that it works for a second and then stops broadcasting.

EDIT 2: After some experimenting, I discovered that it stops when it detects motion.

Comment: Is the camera working?

Comment: Indeed :). As I said, it’s been working all day. I used lsusb to check that the camera is still being detected, which it is.

Comment: And if you reboot the RPi? I run motion day in day out, but the RPi reboots every night.

Comment: As I said in the post, I’ve rebooted the pi several times.

Comment: is your disk full?

Comment: I believe that that was an issue due to jpeg images being stored on the card. To rectify this, I edited /etc/motion/motion.conf and changed the line “output_pictures on” to “output_pictures off”. However, now what seems to be happening is that the camera will work for a second and then stop working.